# Angularjs Extended Directive Controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to extend a directive by passing controllers. I'm able to grab the parent directive's controller through `require` , but I also want to define a controller on the extended controller.

```
.directive('smelly', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function(){
      this.doWork = function(){ alert('smelly work'); };
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, controller){     
      $element.bind('click',function(){
        controller.doWork();
      });
    }
  };
})
.directive('xtSmelly', function(){
  return {    
    controller: function(){
      this.name = "brian";
    },
    require: 'smelly',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, smellyController){
      smellyController.doWork = function(){
        alert('xt-smelly work by: ' + xtSmellyController.name);
      };
    }
  };
})

HTML
<smelly xt-smelly>click me</smelly>
```

How can I access xtSmellyController.name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $scope variable, both controllers will have access to that

```
return {    
controller: function($scope){
  $scope.name = "brian";
},
require: 'smelly',
link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, smellyController){
  smellyController.doWork = function(){
    alert('xt-smelly work by: ' + $scope.name);
  };
}
```

};

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/dYIr36lKtnybxvkUlOJ1?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, it works, but is it the right way? Doesn't it ruin separation of concerns by throwing it into the scope?

Answer (score 1):

require can take an array, the fourth arg in the link function then also becomes an array with the requested controllers in the same order as specified in the require array

```
.directive('smelly', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function(){
      this.doWork = function(){ alert('smelly work'); };
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, controller){     
      $element.bind('click',function(){
        controller.doWork();
      });
    }
  };
})
.directive('xtSmelly', function(){
  return {    
    controller: function(){
      this.name = "brian";
    },
    require: ['smelly', 'xtSmelly'],
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, controllers){
      var smellyController = controllers[0];
      var xtSmellyController = controllers[1];
      smellyController.doWork = function(){
        alert('xt-smelly work by: ' + xtSmellyController.name);
      };
    }
  };
})

HTML
<smelly xt-smelly>click me</smelly>
```